# Transforming ocean color data to GeoTiff temperature raster and load in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I'm doing a project and I need to process the obtained SST data from NASA's Ocean color web (as shown below) for obtaining corresponding temperature raster (GeoTiff format). I'm trying to connect sea surface temperature to observations of marine mammals (min and mix temp for each species).

[image]

After downloading SST data, I processed it with [SeaDas NASA software](https://seadas.gsfc.nasa.gov/) for transforming in GeoTiff temperature raster, however, no temperature data are displayed in QGIS.
I download the SST data through the "SMI HDF" option on the Level 3 SST through AQUA MODIS. The opened on SeaDAS NASA software and exported as GeoTiff but I think I maybe missed something? Because there is no data for the temperature when I put the exported raster it in Qgis

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong or missing a step?

Comment: Could help if you tell us more about your outcome. What do you get? Does QGIS show a raster with values that differ from the ones you were expecting? Does it load a raster with no information at all?

Comment: Please, edit your question to tell us how did you process SST data (download link?) with SeaDas NASA software? What operative system are you using?

Comment: What did you download? Please refer to the Product Definition https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/products/

Comment: Where is **"SMI HDF" option on the Level 3 SST through AQUA MODIS** (as link) because in your image you only have as option to download png images.